# Why does rollup data in Ethereum have to be on chain?

Tags: layer-2, rollups

In this [blog](https://vitalik.ca/general/2021/01/05/rollup.html), it is said

> Rollups move computation (and state storage) off-chain, but keep some
> data per transaction on-chain.
>
> The fact that data is on-chain is key (note: putting data "on IPFS"
> does not work, because IPFS does not provide consensus on whether or
> not any given piece of data is available; the data must go on a
> blockchain). Putting data on-chain and having consensus on that fact
> allows anyone to locally process all the operations in the rollup if
> they wish to, allowing them to detect fraud, initiate withdrawals, or
> personally start producing transaction batches.

I don't understand this comment fully. Why can't the transaction data itself be on IPFS with a pointer to it on the blockchain? Does this not end up being equivalent to putting the data on the blockchain? Consensus would then be used to decide which pointer is valid.

Could someone elaborate on the point being made here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPFS is a cache and not a persistent storage. There is no way to guarantee that any piece of data on IPFS stays there.

Comment: Blobs aren’t persistent too!

Comment: AFAIK blobs are only pruned by a user choice, like old state is pruned in GoEthereum. If you download the block data over peer-to-peer network or run an archive node, blobs are still there. But I could be wrong.